# How to solve Opencv VideoWriter issues with global variables

Tags: python, opencv

I'mm writing this piece of python to display a stream of video from my webcam while at the same time record the video - which I've got working, however I've grayscaled the video streaming to my screen and time stamped it - but my recorded video is in colour! I've included the code below - I've tried using some global variables but nothing worked - any help, greatly appreciated

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time, datetime
import os


genericfilename = "recording"
filetime = str(time.time())
extension = '.avi'
filename = genericfilename + filetime +extension
frames_per_second = 100
res = '720p'
print("NEW FILE NAME: " + filename)

# Set resolution for the video capture
def change_res(cap, width, height):
cap.set(3, width)
cap.set(4, height)

# Standard Video Dimensions Sizes
STD_DIMENSIONS =  {
"480p": (640, 480),
"720p": (1280, 720),
"1080p": (1920, 1080),
"4k": (3840, 2160),
}


# grab resolution dimensions and set video capture to it.
def get_dims(cap, res='1080p'):
width, height = STD_DIMENSIONS["480p"]
if res in STD_DIMENSIONS:
    width,height = STD_DIMENSIONS[res]
## change the current caputre device
## to the resulting resolution
change_res(cap, width, height)
return width, height

# Video Encoding, might require additional installs
VIDEO_TYPE = {
'avi': cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),
#'mp4': cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264'),
'mp4': cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),
}

def get_video_type(filename):
filename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
if ext in VIDEO_TYPE:
  return  VIDEO_TYPE[ext]
return VIDEO_TYPE['avi']

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, get_video_type(filename), 60, 
get_dims(capture, res))

while(True):
ret, frame = capture.read()
out.write(frame)
grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
font = cv2.FONT_ITALIC = 1
cv2.putText(grayFrame, str(datetime.datetime.now()), (-330, 460), font, 3, 
(200, 200, 200), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow('combilift output', grayFrame)
# Press Q on keyboard to  exit 
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
  break
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('r'):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

capture.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what is the problem ? Do you get error message ? always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You save the frame to video, then convert frame to gray.

```
out.write(frame)
grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

If you want your recorded video to be gray, maybe reverse the order of operations and save grayFrame?

```
grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
out.write(grayFrame)
```

If you want to also save the texts, put the text before writing frame to output.

Comment: Tried that, no joy. :/

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at ur code

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, get_video_type(filename), 60, 
.....
while(True):
ret, frame = capture.read()
out.write(frame)
grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

You first save out then convert color

The correct sequence should be

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, get_video_type(filename), 60, 
.....
while(True):
ret, frame = capture.read()
grayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
out.write(grayFrame)
```

I don't have data to test. Just in case you experience some issue with channels. You can use opencv merge(grayFrame,grayFrame,grayFrame) to create a normal 3 channel grey scale image and save to video

Comment: Tried that - didn't work :/ Got this error in my video file: Can't Play this file: ... 0xc10100be

Comment: U tried single channel or three channel? did u used the merge(grayFrame,grayFrame,grayFrame) or cv_GREYTOBGR as I mentioned below? Most of video ecpect 3 channel image instead of 1

Comment: if you still have no luck. post 10 sec of the video up. I`ll try

Comment: no worries guys - found a way around it another way - thanks for all your help!